# Extract blocks of rows from a single-column dataset to separate sequential columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-extraction, submatrix

I have a dataset that includes all data in 1 column. However a new sub-dataset occurs every *n* rows. Using MATLAB, I need to grab each of these sub-datasets and place in a separate sequential column. For example, this:

Column 1

```
1
3
2
1
3
2
1
3
2
```

into this:

Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | ...

```
1  1  1
3  3  3
2  2  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) command like so:

```
my_matrix = reshape(my_vector, num_rows, num_cols);
```

You can also replace `num_cols` in the above with `[]` to have MATLAB automatically figure out how many columns are needed to fit the data into `num_rows` rows. Similarly, you can replace `num_rows` with `[]` and have MATLAB figure out the number of rows needed to fit the data into `num_cols` columns.

Note that MATLAB will throw an error if `my_vector` does not contain *exactly* `num_rows * num_cols` elements. In other words, it will not pad with zeros or truncate your data if the sizes do not match.

Comment: @user3743235 (OP) if you have in your last subdata-set less elements you could/should add a if-case or logical indexing to pad your data with `NaNs`. This has the advantage that, `NaNs`won't be missread as `0` data values and still the reshape would work for any data-set. You could do it with `if mod(numel(data),n)~=0...`. I wrote it as a comment because its just a little addition to @Engineero's solution.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, just the tool I was looking for. Thanks for the additional point too.